# Riverpod: Recompute a provider providing a list of items on receiving updates

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a simple use case where I am trying to recompute a provider providing a list of items on watching an item provider as follows :

```
final itemProvider = StateProvider<Item>((ref) {
    return Item() ;
});

final itemListProvider = Provider<List<Item>>((ref) {
 watch(itemProvider);
...//do something to compute new list
 return computedList ;
});
```

I want the itemListProvider to recompute automatically when itemProvider's state is changed from outside so that the itemListProvider keeps on adding the new items to the existing list it provides.
Is there a way to achieve this in the above particular fashion using Riverpod?
I know I could use a StateNotifierProvider or StateProvider and update the itemList using a state assignment call but I am looking forward to do it reactively.

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished handily with a single StateNotifierProvider.

```dart
class ItemList extends StateNotifier<List<Item>> {
  ItemList() : super([]);

  static final provider = StateNotifierProvider<ItemList, List<Item>>((ref) => ItemList());

  Item _current = Item();
  Item get current => _current;

  void addItem(Item item) {
    _current = item;
    state = [...state, item];
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
// Add an item, which updates the current item
watch(ItemList.provider.notifier).addItem(item);

// Get the current item
final currentItem = watch(ItemList.provider.notifier).current;

// Get the List<Item> from state
final itemList = watch(ItemList.provider);
```

---

If you *really* want to avoid StateNotifierProvider, you could do the following, but I would highly recommend you to use the first approach. Anyways:

```dart
final itemProvider = StateProvider<Item>((ref) => Item());

final itemListProvider = StateProvider<List<Item>>((ref) => []);

final computedListProvider = Provider<List<Item>>((ref) {
  final item = ref.watch(itemProvider);
  final itemList = ref.watch(itemListProvider);
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (itemList.state.contains(item.state)) return;
    itemList.state = [...itemList.state, item.state];
  });

  return itemList.state;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! However, I was searching for a better alternative or probably a feature where the provider could compute itself with the existing and new data both without external addToList state calls. Could that be done somehow?

Comment: I'm unsure why you would want to complicate things that way. Could you expand in your question as to why StateNotifier doesn't work for your use case?

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately :(

Comment: @AkashGorai Okay, I added an alternative solution that finishes what you started in your question.

Comment: I didn't realise we could use postFrameCallback here :D.

Comment: Why do you suggest to use the StateNotifier approach though? I know it's recommended in examples but... I wanted  the itemList provider to contain the logic to what to do with the data itself. Isn't the items getting added reactively better than calling a method to do it?

Comment: I mean, both ways accomplish the same task with one function call, but the notifier approach is cleaner, more concise, less prone to bugs.

Comment: @AkashGorai If this solved your problem, please mark this as the accepted answer. I think this could be helpful to future readers to see two approaches to a problem like this.

Comment: I am not sure how clean the second solution is to my use case/request. It probably does the job and I mark it correct. However, it's definitely very hacky and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Best approaches are

1. For any input parameter that should be evaluated as part of the provider you can use riverPod .family. Link here (https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family/)
2. Alternatively as per documentation itemListProvider should get re-evaluated if itemProvider is updated. Incase it is not for your usecase then in your widget you can call ref.refresh to re-evaluate the provider. For Refresh perform like below and change your provider to FutureProvider

   Future _refresh(){
   ref.refresh(itemListProvider);
   return ref.read(itemListProvider.future);
   }